# Examples Criterion to determine conditions a series is Fourier or not an examples

Tags: fourier-analysis

A Criterion to determine whether a series is Fourier or not .
A example of a function thet satisface Hölder criterion but not Dini.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but do you need to know is a series is the Fourier transform of a function?

Comment: If a function satisfies a Holder condition at $x$ with exponent $\alpha > 0$, then it satisfies the Dini condition at $x$ as well. That's an easy check.